# Caliburn.Micro Dispose ViewModel when closed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, idisposable

In a WPF application I'm using caliburn.micro and a tabbed interface to open and close multiple views.

```
Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
```

When I'm open new tabs (views), I can see the consumed memory for the exe process is increasing, that is obvious.

But when I'm closing the tabs(views), the consumed memory is still same.  Which means consumed memory for the closed `ViewModels` are not garbage collected yet. (I have waited for long time to observe this).

Initially the application size was ~60000K after opening many tabs (around 20) Its increased to ~500000k. My `ViewModels` are fairly heavy. Once  I closed all the tabs the the consumed memory is still ~500000k.

I think I have to implement `IDisposable` interface for dispose `ViewModels` when it closes.

1. Can any one help me to solve this issue by providing sample code?
2. Do I need to call `Dispose()` method inside overrided `OnDeactivate(bool close)` Method?
3. Do I need to set Properties of the `ViewModel` to `null`?

Comment: I don't think implementing `IDisposable` is going to help. The memory won't be freed up whilst you are retaining references to the view models. When you're done with the reference, null it out to remove the reference. The GC can then kick in and free them.

Comment: _"allocated memory"_ has many definitions and is not so easy to measure. Move on, you don't have a problem here.

Comment: @Henk It's "consumed memory" not "allocated memory". I have edited the question now.

Comment: Same difference. You do not have an indication of a memory leak.

Comment: @Henk, but why the consumed memory is continuously increasing, but never decreasing?

Comment: @Jack Hughes I'm instantiating ViewModels inside a static class using  'Activator.CreateInstance()' Method and Activating it using `caliburn.micro` `Conductor`. Apart from this there is no any hardcoded references. What i'am missing here?

Comment: If you are using a Bootstrapper, then I would bet that your container is retaining the view model references. When you are finished with a view model, tell your container to release it.

Comment: @Jack Hughes Is that something I have to dealt with Conductor? It would be highly appreciated, If you can explain this with some example code. I don't have deep knowledge in caliburn.micro

Comment: Allocating memory is hard, so the CLR tends to hold onto it as long as possible.  You shouldn't be worrying about this unless you're experiencing OOM exceptions or performance issues.  Oh, how .net developers bedevil themselves with task manager...